# Display images from a database into a PHP page

Tags: php

Im wondering what can I do to make images from a database on Php display on my page.
This is what I have

images .php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY name ASC ";

            $result = $db->query($query);
            $num_result = $result->num_rows;

            echo "<h1> Images</h1>";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++){

                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $name = $row['name'];
                $URL = $row['imageURL'];


                $array = array($URL);
            }

foreach ($array as $image){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><img class="coupons" src="'.$image.'"/></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';

          }
```

This is just printing only one image and I have 10 in my database, what can I do or change to  print all of the images from the database? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
$array = array($URL);
```

into

```
$array[] = $URL;
```

And add before line:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++){
```

add line:

```
$array = array();
```

Comment: don't forget to assign your array before the `for` loop unless you like errors.

Comment: True, I've added info to answer

Comment: this worked great! thanks a lot and yeh added the $array = array(); at the top

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$array = array();//initialize here 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++){
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $name = $row['name'];
            $URL = $row['imageURL'];
            $array[] = $URL;
    }
```

You can rewrite your code as,

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $name = $row['name'];
        $URL = $row['imageURL'];    
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><img class="coupons" src="'.$URL.'"/></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY name ASC ";

$result = $db->query($query);
$num_result = $result->num_rows;

$array = array();

echo "<h1> Images</h1>";

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++){

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $name = $row['name'];
    $URL = $row['imageURL'];


    $array[] = URL;
}

foreach ($array as $image){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><img class="coupons" src="'.$image.'"/></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

You also had a trailing `<tr>` which may cause styling issues