# Actual implementation of 5-star rating system

Tags: php, image, system, rating

I want to implement a 5-star rating system into my web page. I'm totally new to using php, but I've got the system set up and working. I am able to create as many rating boxes as I want and have them working, but my question is..

How do I place the rating stars near my images? In this case, I want 10 different images to be rated. The code I use on my "page.php":

Array:

```
<?php
include("settings.php");
connect();
$ids=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
?>

<html>
```

Body:

```
 <?php
    for($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++)
        {
            $rating_tableName     = 'ratings';
         $id=$ids[$i];
     $q="SELECT total_votes, total_value FROM $rating_tableName WHERE id=$id";
    $r=mysql_query($q);
    if(!$r) echo mysql_error();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
        $v=$row['total_votes'];
        $tv=$row['total_value'];
        $rat=$tv/$v;

        }



        $j=$i+1;
        $id=$ids[$i];
    echo'<div class="product">
               Rate Item '.$j.'
                <div id="rating_'.$id.'" class="ratings">';
                    for($k=1;$k<6;$k++){
                        if($rat+0.5>$k)$class="star_".$k."  ratings_stars ratings_vote";
                        else $class="star_".$k." ratings_stars ratings_blank";
                        echo '<div class="'.$class.'"></div>';
                        }
                    echo' <div class="total_votes"><p class="voted"> Rating: <strong>'.@number_format($rat).'</strong>/5 ('.$v. '  vote(s) cast) 
                </div>
            </div></div>';}
    ?>
```

Comment: So apart from the potential divide-by-zero issue at `$rat=$tv/$v;`, what exactly is the problem here? What is stopping you from putting the stars next to the images?

Comment: *"How do I place the rating stars near my images?"* - You use `img src` based on the column that holds the image information.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! The problem i'm having is that I don't know how to link the image files to my array. Of course I know how to img src="..." but I never used it in an array or php

Comment: You're welcome. Something like `echo '<img src="'.explode(',', $row['col'])[0].'"/>';` or `echo '<img src="'$row['col'].'"/>';`, or see this Q&A's http://stackoverflow.com/q/23477314/ although it's `mysqli_` based.

Comment: Thanks Fred! So what I make up from that, is that I have to add a column to my mySQL table that holds the img URL's?

Comment: Exactly Tommie. You could either store the full url to the image(s) in 5 different rows, or just the image name. If you're just going to use the image name only without the path/url, then you will need to make sure your code fetches it/them from the right folder.

Comment: Allright, i'll try that! Does it reason the file location from the webroot or from the folder location my .php file is in?

Comment: Depending on the script's location of execution, it will vary. If executed from the root, and having your images stored in a sub-folder, then you'd just do `img src="images/star1.xxx"`. But if you're running your script from outside the root, then you'd need to do something like `img src="../images/star1.xxx"` or try and use either the full URL/http call, or server path such as `img src="/var/user/you/public/images/star1.xxx"` but you can't fail using a `http://` call `img src="http://example.com/images/star1.xxx"`

Comment: Or just tack it on to your row call `echo '<img src="images/" ."'$row['col'].'"/>';` something like that. My syntax (quotes) could be a bit off.

Comment: Well.. It works! Except for the fact that it doesn't output the dot in "image.jpg" (it sets the image URL to "imgjpg").

Probably very easy to fix, but like I said, i'm new to php

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Could you give me any hints on how to prevent the divide-by-zero issue you mentioned?

Comment: Something like this, perhaps: `$rat = ($v>0) ? $tv/$v : 0;`. (The ternary operator (`«X» ? «Y» : «Z»`) evaluates `«X»` and returns `«Y»` if `«X»` is true, or `«Z»` otherwise.)